# Display a list of PDF-files in the sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I'm making this site in both static HTML and Wordpress (I have made some changes to the theme folder). The site is close to complete, but I would like to make a new box in the sidebar, where it's really easy to upload different PDF-files (a list). For instance:

- newsletter1.pdf
- newsletter2.pdf
- newsletter3.pd

I'm making the site for my uncle, and he still needs help with the remote for the TV, so it must be as user friendly as possible.

What I'm after is a widget or just some way, to show a list of PDF-files in the sidebar. If it involves changing the theme-code, then that's fine. It should just be as easy as possible to insert ned PDF-files in this widget.

I've thought of all different kind of ideas. I have been looking for a widget, where you can insert media-files. But all these widgets haven't been updated the past two years. Is that because it has become a part of the Wordpress core, and I'm missing something?

I've also thought of, if it was possible to have a PHP-widget or something like that, that includes something - but that's a terrible idea.

Ideally, it would be cool, if there was a widget, where you could just go in and add PDF-files, as if it was a post. Or maybe a widget that takes all content from a post (or a page) and displays the whole thing (since then I could just explain to my uncle, that he just had to put the page or the post in the right place, and then it would pull all the links from that post or page to the sidebar widget).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the code below:

```
<ul id="attachments">
<?php foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { 

    if ($attachment ->post_mime_type != 'image/jpeg') {
    $filetipe = $attachment->post_mime_type;
    $signs = array(".", ",", "-", "application", "/");
    $filetype = str_replace($signs, "", $filetipe);

?>

    <li class="<?php echo $filetype; ?>"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>" target="blank"><?php  echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); ?> </a></li>

<?php } } ?>
</ul>
```

you ca get all the attachments of a post except for images.
now you can just edit your sidebar.php and query the post that has those pdf files attached. this will be the complete code for your sidebar.php file, where 5 is the ID of your post

```
        <?php
    query_posts( 'p=5' );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'posts_per_page' => 666,

    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {?>

<ul id="attachments">
    <?php foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { 

        if ($attachment ->post_mime_type != 'image/jpeg') {
        $filetipe = $attachment->post_mime_type;
        $signs = array(".", ",", "-", "application", "/");
        $filetype = str_replace($signs, "", $filetipe);

    ?>

        <li class="<?php echo $filetype; ?>"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>" target="blank"><?php  echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); ?> </a></li>

    <?php } } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php   } ?>    
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: It gives me this error: [[[   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/srvestle/public_html/svin/wp-content/themes/twentyten/sidebar.php on line 21
wp_reset_query(); ?>   ]]] . And here is line 21 in the code:   [[[ 
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {         ]]].

I don't understand the code 100%, so I'm struggling to debug it. Anyone?

Comment: i modified the code a bit. (there had to be an php opening tag before wp reset query)

Answer (score 0):

I found this Wordpress plugin that did the trick. It pulls all the PDF-files from a given post or page and displays it in the widget. It gave me a couple of problems though, but nothing that couldn't be solved with alittle fiddling...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cop-pdf-attachment-menu/ and it's called: AGC: COP PDF Attachment Menu